# why the error says LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_thread-vc120-mt-gd-1_58.lib'?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, linker

Note: this is not a question on how to solve the error, but how it knows the boost file name.

I'm writing a C++ program using Boost's thread library, so in one of my cpp file I put

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
```

Since [`thread` is not a boost module that only including header files will do](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#header-only-libraries), naturally, Visual Studio is looking for a library.

However, I always thought which library to link, is specified in `Project > Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies`, and the paths are defined at `Project > Properties > Linker > General > Additional Library Directories`. How could Visual Studio knows the exact name of the boost lib file?

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 7.

Comment: ***How could Visual Studio knows the exact name of the boost lib file?*** There is a #pragma comment( lib libraryname) statement in the headers. That specifies the exact name.

Comment: It's because boost uses [Visual Studio auto-linking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bx5yfk7t.aspx). See [How boost auto-linking makes choice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22805082/how-boost-auto-linking-makes-choice).