# Boost build a new version with VS 2019

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost

I downloaded the latest version from https://www.boost.org/ and I need to build in VS2019 (C++, 32bits) when I build the files contains mt and the toolset

My question is how I can remove the mt and the toolset from the lib and dlls ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boost library file names describe what they support and how they were built. In your case they support multithreading and were built with VS2019 (as opposed to MinGw, Clang or an earlier version of visual studio). For more information see: [how can i decode boost library naming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715164/how-can-i-decode-the-boost-library-naming).

`boost` uses auto linking with `visual studio`, see [how boost auto linking makes choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22805082/how-boost-auto-linking-makes-choice), so the library file names must match those that are required.

You haven't said why you want to "remove the mt and the toolset from the lib and dlls".
If it is to get `boost` to link with an existing project, then you'll need to build `boost` with the correct version of visual studio and without multi-threading, e.g.:

```
b2 toolset=msvc-??? threading=single ...
```

See: [b2 invocation properties](https://boostorg.github.io/build/manual/develop/index.html#bbv2.overview.invocation.properties).

Comment: I was able to remove only the boost version, because we don't want to change each time the include when we change the boost version